# How to solve HTTP Request Forwarding issue in symfony2?

Tags: php, apache, symfony, apache2

I am using symfony2.3.1 application and i have issue of Unvalidated HTTP Request Forwarding. And I am much confused that how can i solve this issue. Do i need to configure in apache2 server or i should do something in symfony2 application.

The issue is user send malicious requests to any remote web server via the web proxy server of my application.
my application will act as a web proxy, and it will appear as if the attack originated from this application instead of attacker’s client.

Please help!!

Comment: What do you mean by _HTTP Request Forwarding_ ?! There are several ways to pass a request to another script / server / domain.

Comment: Can you post more info? An error message and somecode would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [owasp.org](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A10-Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards):

> How Do I Prevent "Unvalidated Redirects and Forwards"?
>
> Safe use of redirects and forwards can be done in a number of ways:
>
> 1. Simply avoid using redirects and forwards.
> 2. If used, don’t involve user parameters in calculating the destination. This can usually be done.
> 3. If destination parameters can’t be avoided, ensure that the supplied value is valid, and authorized for the user.
>
> It is recommended that any such destination parameters be a mapping value, rather than the actual URL or portion of the URL, and that server side code translate this mapping to the target URL.

The key point in solving your issue is that last sentence. Using such a map will give you full control over what's redirected/forwarded and what not.